# Make first line of textarea be on same position as bullet in list-item

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have `<ul>` list.

For every `li` I've modify bullets style:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li:before{
    content: "\2022";
    font-size: 170%;
    margin-left: -16px;
}
```

And my list looks like :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <textarea name="txtBullet1" rows="2" cols="70" id="txtBullet1" tabindex="20" onkeyup="maxLen(this);" required="required" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But textArea is upper than my bullet. I've tried `padding` and `margin` to move it lower, but doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align:middle;` with textarea and bullet

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li:before{
    content: "\2022";
    font-size: 170%;
    margin-left: -16px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
textarea {
  padding:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <textarea name="txtBullet1" rows="2" cols="70" id="txtBullet1" tabindex="20" onkeyup="maxLen(this);" required="required" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is what I need. Thanks